# Did the apostles travel with their wives?

Tags: 1-corinthians, history

I was doing some research for an answer and came across this verse:

> This is my defense to those who would examine me. Do we not have the right to eat and drink? *Do we not have the right to take along a believing wife, as do the other apostles and the brothers of the Lord and Cephas?* Or is it only Barnabas and I who have no right to refrain from working for a living?—1<sup>st</sup> Corinthians 9:3-6 ([ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/1+Corinthians+9/))

Does verse 5 indicate that some of the other apostles (and possibly even Barnabas) traveled with their wives? It seems to indicate this in the English but I'm wondering if the original language or outside supporting documentation provides more clues as to what Paul is talking about here.

Comment: Do I get to say welcome to BH, btw?

Comment: man, how did I screw up the book? :(

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it does state that other apostles travelled with their wives. The Greek word used for "take along" is *periagō*, which the King James translates "lead about". The use of this particular word would indicate more than just having or leading a wife, but taking her around with you.

Comment: As a footnote, while researching this question I came across an interesting statement in a commentary on the passage:
"During the lifetime of Jesus the disciples had 'left all' to follow him (Mark 10:28), but apparently this practice had not continued during the time following the resurrection of Jesus."